# emacs insert-kbd-macro... [No Match]

Tags: emacs, elisp

I created a macro using <kbd>C-x (</kbd> ... did some actions ... <kbd>C-x )</kbd>, then saved the macro <kbd>C-x C-k n</kbd> my-macro. Then I generated the code for my .emacs file using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` my-macro.  I restarted emacs and tested my-macro, works fine.

Now I need to edit the macro, so I use <kbd>C-x C-k e</kbd>, then <kbd>M-x</kbd> my-macro.  I make edits, save and run a test of the new my-macro and it works fine.

When I go to generate my-macro for my .emacs, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` my-macro... [No Match]

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I regenerate or save the new my-macro for my .emacs?

I would try to edit the macro in .emacs directly, but it's generated as a lambda function which looks very confusing to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done much with keyboard macros. Nevertheless, a bit of research revealed the following.

1. `insert-kbd-macro` takes keyboard macros from the variables `last-kbd-macro` or `kmacro-ring` and not from the global `obarray` where function definitions are stored. You stored your macro as the function inserted by `insert-kbd-macro`. (That is essentially what `fset` does.) Therefore, `insert-kbd-macro` did not find your macro.
2. Two possible ways to edit the keyboard macro:

   1. Save the keyboard macro as you have done it. Edit the first string within the list argument of `kmacro-exec-ring-item`.
   2. Alternatively, you can edit your keyboard macro `my-macro` with `edit-kbd-macro`. Afterwards you can re-insert it with `(insert (format "%S" (symbol-function 'my-macro)))`.

Maybe, someone has a better answer...

Note, you can also assign that first string to a key with `global-set-key` or `local-set-key`.